# Running custom artisan command in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have custom command like:

```
php artisan down --message="this is my custom message."
```

Now I want to use this command in my controller with input fields.

I know I can use `Call` method like `Artisan::call('down');` but my issue is how to add `--message=""` part into that call method?

## Data

this is what I'm sending to controller currently:

```
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "wqHyTNmDhArtonB0gwhIbCipSsStv0WnoASQm34u"
  "maintenance_message" => "this is my custom message."
  "maintenance" => "active"
]
```

Now based on `maintenance` value i will call `Artisan::call('up');` or `Artisan::call('down');` but the question is **how do i add `maintenance_message` into it?**

## Code

This is my current function.

```
public function MaintenanceMode(Request $request){
  if($request->input('maintenance') == 'active'){
    //maintenance_message
    Session::flash('danger', 'Site is successfully in maintenance mode.');
    return Artisan::call('down');
  }else{
    //maintenance_message
    Session::flash('success', 'Site is ONLINE.');
    return Artisan::call('up');
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved

Here is what I did to add my message part into artisan command

```
return Artisan::call('down', ['--message'     => $request->input('maintenance_message')]);
```

Hope it help others.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation has some examples of this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

> The call method accepts either the command's name or class as the first argument, and an array of command parameters as the second argument. The exit code will be returned:
>
> ```
> Route::get('/foo', function () {
>     $exitCode = Artisan::call('email:send', [
>         'user' => 1, '--queue' => 'default'
>     ]);
>
>     //
> });
> ```